# If the number of degrees in certain angle is added to the number of grades the angle is $152$, find the angle in degrees.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, angle

If the number of degrees in certain angle is added to the number of grades the angle is $152$, find the angle in degrees.

My Attempt
Let $x$ be the angle. Then no of degrees in $x$ is $\dfrac {10x}{9}$.

Comment: @Ak19 Neither.  It is the number of degrees plus the number of grades.

Comment: Sorry I  misread it.

Comment: You mean "if $x$ is the number of grades in the angle?"  Why aren't you using $152$ anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $1^\circ=\frac{10}9^g$, so we have, when $x$ is the value in degrees,
$$x+\frac{10}9x=\frac{19}9x=152$$
$$x=\frac{152×9}{19}=72$$